# Hide show BottomBar using hidesBottomBarWhenPushed

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I've hide BottomBar when performing segue from root using

`hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true`

which is working fine but in one screen i need to show BottomBar back

i'm using `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = false`
but it's not working.

**Flow**

[image]

Can anyone help me to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think the `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` only works when you push a viewController on the stack. When you are coming back to your `initialViewController` you are actually poping back, not pushing ahead in the navigation stack.

One quick thing that you can do is *explicitly hide* the bottom `tabBar` (in **viewDidLoad** or **viewWillAppear**) when you come to your screen B and **show** it when you leave from there (**viewWillDisappear**)